# Batch: Unable to assign an array to a variable

Tags: batch, array

I am not able to assign an array to a variable:

```
set persons[0].FirstName=Richard
set persons[0].lastName=DuponT
set persons[1].FirstName=Romain
set persons[1].lastName=DuponD


set x=0
REM Works:
call echo %%persons[0].FirstName%%      
call echo %%persons[%x%].FirstName%%
REM Fails:
SET var=%%persons[%x%]%%
echo %var.FirstName%
```

`SET var=` is failing, so the following echo is too. How do I assign an array to a variable?

Comment: Unlike variables `persons[0].FirstName` and `persons[0].lastName`, variable `persons[0]` isn't defined… That's why `SET var=%%persons[%x%]%%` as well as `call SET var=%%persons[%x%]%%` must assign an empty string to `var`.

Comment: You can't. `cmd` does not support arrays, other than the hack you are already using.

Comment: Cmd is not a language where you can just sprinkle dots in your code and make it work like (say) vb.net.

Comment: Why aren't you using **PowerShell**?

Comment: Or even VBScript?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, batch does not have any formal concept of arrays or objects. You are simply defining 4 environment variables whose names give the appearance of an array of objects.

Environment variable names may contain any character except null (0x00) or `=`. Values may contain any character except null.

You could copy your pseudo object with the following:

```
set x=0
for /f "delims=. tokens=1*" %%A in ('set persons[%x%]') do set "obj.%%B
echo %obj.FirstName%
```

`set persons[%x%]` expands to `set persons[0]`, which in turn lists all environment variables with a name that begin with persons[0]. That will produce the following output:

```
persons[0].FirstName=Richard
persons[0].lastName=DuponT
```

The FOR /F command with an IN() clause surrounded by single quotes iterates the output of the command. The DELIMS option specifies that tokens are delimited by `.` characters, and the TOKENS option specifies that the first token is stored in %%A, and all remaining content is stored in %%B.

So for the first iteration, %%A = `persons[0]`, and %%B = `FirstName=Richard`. So the SET command becomes `set "obj.FirstName=Richard"`.

If you are going to work with complex data structures in batch, then you are probably going to want to read up about delayed expansion (`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` coupled with `!var!` instead of `%var%`), batch quoting and escape rules, and the use of `CALL` with doubled percents to get an extra round of variable expansion (you already used this without understanding how it works). That is just the tip of the iceberg. There is a tremendous amount of arcane knowledge needed to fully understand how everything works.

If you really want to go down that rabbit hole, then see [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/1012053).